# Match x out of y groups in Java regex

Tags: java, regex

Is it possible to write a regex pattern in Java that will match, for example, 2 out of 3 (or 3 out of 4 etc) groups?

For example, I have the following regex:

```
((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]))
```

which will only allow patterns that match all three groups - i.e. it must contain a number AND a lowercase character AND an uppercase character.  I'd like to make it so that it will validate a pattern that contains at least two out of the three groups (e.g. a number and an Uppercase character OR a lower and uppercase characters).

Is it doable in a single statement or am I going to have to write separate regexes and loop through them?

Comment: `(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])|(?=.\d)(?=.[A-Z])`

Comment: I'd suggest that you test the conditions separately if you have more conditions. For small cases, you can still list out all combinations, but it will become a mess when you have to deal with more.

Comment: You can actually do this in .NET regex using balanced capture groups...but this isn't available in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need alternations to account for all the possible scenarios:

```
((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]))
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wG1rD1/1) that also matches the whole string with `matches()`:

```
((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])|^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])|^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])).*
```

Comment: This will become so much more complex for higher number of groups. Isn't there a shorter and more generic way?

Comment: Generic way is not to use regex for this. Regular expressions are not a panaceum. Whenever the rules are becoming to complex, you should use regular code.

Comment: Thank you. I had already gone down the route of using regular code to check alternatives but I wanted to be sure I wasn't missing something obvious.